# Macro to insert data into next blank row or column in another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 sheets in this workbook, GP Data is the input sheet in this workbook,
and the other 4 sheets requires me to copy paste data from specific cells of the GP Data Sheet and update into the next blank row of the remaining sheets.

Column A in SheetX,Y,Z is the date which is dragged down from the previous date every time I copy the data over similarly to Row 6 in Raw Sheet.

```
Sub Prism2ndStep()
'
' Prism2ndStep Macro
'

'
    Range("P12:R14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("RAW").Select
    Range("DC7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("CZ6:DB6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("CZ6:DE6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("CZ6:DE6").Select
    Sheets("GP Data").Select
    Range("S12:S14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DX").Select
    Range("B39").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("GP Data").Select
    Range("T12:T14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DY").Select
    Range("B39").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("GP Data").Select
    Range("U12:U14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DZ").Select
    Range("B39").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A38").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A38:A39"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A38:A39").Select
    Sheets("DY").Select
    Range("A38").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A38:A39"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A38:A39").Select
    Sheets("DX").Select
    Range("A38").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A38:A39"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A38:A39").Select
    Sheets("GP Data").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use : `.Select, .Copy, .Paste` method

Most of the time, you can use this pattern (only 1 line) :

```
Sheets("DZ").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("GP Data").Range("C1").Value
```

(1 cell)

```
Sheets("DZ").Range("B1:B4").Value = Sheets("GP Data").Range("A1:A4").Value
```

(multiple cells - be sure source and cible are the same size)

Comment: What does the above code do & where should I place it in my code?

Comment: first line means : cell A1 in sheet DZ get the value of cell C1 in sheet GP Data